# Laravel DB::raw bind parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have problem when trying to bind the data in to query.
I'm use php framework Laravel 5.7 version.

Trying to bind data this way:

```
DB::raw("(
        select 
            10 * FLOOR(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) - 3600 )  
                * (drivers.salary_per_hour / 3600) / 10)
        from assignments
        where 
            assignments.driver_id = drivers.id 
            and assignments.driving_day 
                between STR_TO_DATE('?', '%Y-%m-%d') 
                and STR_TO_DATE('?', '%Y-%m-%d') ) 
        as salary",[
            $dates['from'],
            $dates['to']
        ])
```

and receive null as result.

$dates array values:

```
['from' => '2019-03-01', 'to' => '2019-03-31']
```

But if I'm doing it this way it work fine, but there is SQL injection, and I'm think it will be better if I'm bind the data.

```
$drivers = Driver::select([
        'id', 'name', 'surname', 'phone', 'driver_status','driver_status', 'updated_at', 'updated_at', 'photo',
        'salary_per_hour',
        DB::raw("(
            select 10 * FLOOR(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) - 3600 )  * (drivers.salary_per_hour / 3600) / 10)
            from assignments
            where assignments.driver_id = drivers.id 
            and assignments.driving_day between STR_TO_DATE('".$dates['from']."', '%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE('".$dates['to']."', '%Y-%m-%d') ) as salary"),
        DB::raw("(
            select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) - 3600 ))
            from assignments
            where assignments.driver_id = drivers.id 
            and assignments.driving_day between STR_TO_DATE('".$dates['from']."', '%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE('".$dates['to']."', '%Y-%m-%d') ) as worked_hours"),
    ])->whereHas('assigments', function ($query) use ($dates) {
        $query->whereBetween('driving_day', [$dates['from'], $dates['to']]);
    });

    $table = $drivers->paginate(15);
```

What's wrong in my data binding?

===

I'm tried this way

```
and assignments.driving_day 
between STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d') 
and STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d') )
```

and got error:

```
QLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select `id`, `name`, `surname`, `phone`, `driver_status`, `driver_status`, `updated_at`, `updated_at`, `photo`,  ▶
            select 10 * FLOOR(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) - 3600 )  * (drivers.salary_per_hour / 3600) / 10)
            from assignments
            where assignments.driver_id = drivers.id 
            and assignments.driving_day between STR_TO_DATE('2019-03-07', '%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE('2019-03-31', '%Y-%m-%d') ) as salary, (
            select SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) - 3600 ))
            from assignments
            where assignments.driver_id = drivers.id 
            and assignments.driving_day between STR_TO_DATE('2019-03-07', '%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE('2019-03-31', '%Y-%m-%d') ) as worked_hours, (
    select 10 * FLOOR(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) - 3600 )  * (drivers.salary_per_hour / 3600) / 10)
    from assignments
    where assignments.driver_id = drivers.id 
    and assignments.driving_day between STR_TO_DATE(2019-03-07, '%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE(2019-03-31, '%Y-%m-%d') ) as test from `drivers` where exists (select * from `assignments` where `drivers`.`id` = `assignments`.`driver_id` and `driving_day` between ? and ?) limit 15 offset 0)
```

Comment: You need to remove the quotes around the `?`s.

Answer (score 0):

In your query:

```
and assignments.driving_day 
    between STR_TO_DATE('?', '%Y-%m-%d') 
    and STR_TO_DATE('?', '%Y-%m-%d') )
```

You should not quote the bind parameters (`'?'`). Lavarel, as other database interfaces, handles that level of encapsulation for you.

You want:

```
and assignments.driving_day 
    between STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d') 
    and STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d') )
```

Comment: @VardanNersesyan: the last part of your query also requires parameters: `(select * from assignments where drivers.id = assignments.driver_id and driving_day between ? and ?)`. You need to bind them the same way you bound other parameters.